# Different between sympath commands in Windbg

Tags: symbols, windbg

What is the difference between the following commands?

```
.sympath cache*c:\CachedSymbols;srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

.sympath srv*c:\CachedSymbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Comment: have you gone through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbol-path  explain whst you dont understand in this documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference betwen the 2 exact commands that you posted.

However, consider the following:

```
.sympath cache*c:\CachedSymbols;srv*server1;srv*server2
```

then, symbols of both servers will go into the same cache, whereas

```
.sympath srv*c:\CachedSymbols*server1;srv*c:\OtherPlace*server2
```

allows you to define 2 different places.

And a

```
.sympath cache*c:\CachedSymbols;srv*C:\Server1*server1;srv*C:\Server2*server2
```

even stores each symbol twice, once per server and both in the cache.